# Cannot get selection from one page to another - need to know what choice user chose

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to let the user select one 'thing' from a list (from the database), then go find other stuff in the database using that record.  But I cannot get the selection info from the selection page.

I'll try to make this a pretty complete snapshot of the relevant code, but I may remove too much or leave too much in, sorry.

my models.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^$', 'dblook.views.index', name='home'),
url(r'^dblook3/', 'dblook.views.try3', name='home2'),
url(r'^dblook4/', 'dblook.views.try4', name='home3'),
)
```

my dblook/models.py:

```
from django.db import models
class serial_number(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.serialno
        #return self.question
    class Meta:
        managed=False
        db_table='serial_number'
    sn_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    serialno = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    comment = models.ForeignKey(comment,null=True,db_column='comment')
```

my views.py (I will skip all the imports other than the database model import.  If anyone really wants them I'll update with them)

```
from dblook.models import *
class SerialnoSelectForm(forms.Form):
    serialno = forms.CharField(max_length=16)
    selected = forms.BooleanField()

class serialform(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = serial_number
        exclude=('comment','sn_id')
    selected = forms.BooleanField()

class snselect(forms.Form):
    sno = forms.ChoiceField()

def try3(request):
    if ( request.POST ):
        output = "HEllo world, thanks for posting"
        return HttpResponse(output)
    else:
        sslst = snselect(serial_number.objects.filter(serialno__startswith="A128").order_by('-serialno'))
        t = loader.get_template('select_serialno.html')
        c = Context({
            'sslst': sslst,
            })
        c.update(csrf(request))
        return HttpResponse(t.render(c))

def try4(request,dsn):
    if ( request.POST ):
        output = "HEllo world, thanks for posting to 4"
        return HttpResponse(output)
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Error")
```

And my template (select_serialno.html) is:

```
<h1>Select a serial number</h1>
 <ul>
   <form method='post' action'='/dbtest4/{{serial_number.sn_id}}/showme'>
     {% csrf_token %}
     {% for sn in sslst %}
     <input type="submit" name="sn.serialno" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{choice.id}}"/>
     <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ sn.serialno }}</label><br/>
     {% endfor %}
     <input type="submit" value="data" />
</form>
```

When I go to dblook3, I get a nice list from the database of serial numbers, along with a button that, if I hit goes immediately to the dblook4 URL (in this case, its ALWAYS '/dbtest4//showme/' instead of something like '/dbtest4/3/showme/).  Unfortunately, I cannot seem to have any way to tell what button they hit.

No matter WHAT I put in for the 'stuff' in `<form method='post' action'='/dbtest/{{stuff}}/showme'>`, it is always empty.

I also tried things like `if( 'choice' in request.POST ):` in try4 in veiws.py, but that didn't work either.

So, how do I get ANY information about what was selected from 'look3' over to 'look4'?  I'll take just about anything...  However, if you can explain why I'm doing that hopefully your answer will not only solve my problem, but help others understand...

(if the above looks pretty 'evolutionary' that's because I've been hacking on this for 3 days now...)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to `POST` the information to the `look4` dblook form:

```
<form method='post' action'='{% url dblook.views.try4 %}'>
```

At the moment you have `/dbtest/{{serial_number.sn_id}}/showme` which doesn't make any sense. You don't have a `serial_number` variable in your context so I don't know where that comes from. You have `def try4(request,dsn):` as your view definition which suggests that you are trying to load information on the `try4` view depending on what was selected fromt he `try3` view (although I am guessing this as you haven't explained what you are trying to do). If that is the case, you need to do that based on the data passed via POST instead of url parameters. Something very vaguely like the following:

```
def try4(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = snselect(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.cleaned_data
            # Get the selected item from your choice field and retrieve the 
            # corresonding model object with that id
            ...
```

Comment: Sorry it doesn't make any sense, but I thought I was doing what the tutorial said (specifically djangoproject.com's tutorial03).  What I'm trying to do is display all the serial numbers in the database and let the user choose 1 of them, then I go look up OTHER stuff in the database based upon their choice (foreign key references, to be precise).  So, step 1 is display the list (try3 above).  When they submit that form, I want to find what serial number they chose. (try4 above)

Comment: The next problem is:  form.is_valid seems to be false.  Note that snselect is a single thing, but the response (I'm assuming) is the entire page of a few hundred serial numbers, one of which the user has selected.

Comment: Indeed, when I say "return HttpResponse(form['chooseme'])" instead of `if form.is_valid` above I appear to get a single (empty, as far as I can tell right now) thing.